# find: multiple `-exec`s with conditions

Tags: find, xargs

I am trying to include the standard C package `stdint.h` to files which have the word `LARGE_INTEGER`, as a part of conversion from Windows to Linux drivers as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212813/16920) for datatypes.
I know the previous threads about find and xargs, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159780/16920) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159780/16920).

Code where GNU find part is based mainly on this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212829/16920):

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f                                                      \
    \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \)                                   \
    -exec ggrep -Pl "LARGE_INTEGER" {} +
```

and its pseudocode extension where I want also that the files must contain the word `LARGE_INTEGER`

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f                                                \
    \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \)                             \
    -and -exec ggrep -Pl "LARGE_INTEGER" {} \;                     \
    | xargs gsed -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/'
```

where I am uncertain about `-and` and giving

```
gsed: can't read /tmp/: No such file or directory
...
```

I followed examples in commandlinefu [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3702/kill-processes-that-have-been-running-for-more-than-a-week).

How can you combine a new command to the find based on GNU SED?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use<sup>1</sup> `find` with two `-exec` actions e.g.:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qF SOME_STRING {} \; -exec sed 'COMMAND' {} \;
```

The second command will run only if the first one evaluates to *true* i.e. *exit code* `0` so `sed` will process the file in question only if the file contains *SOME_STRING*. It's easy to see how it works:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qF SOME_STRING {} \; -print
```

it should list only those files that contain *SOME_STRING*. Sure, you can always chain more than two expressions and also use operators like `!` (negation) e.g.:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qF THIS {} \; ! -exec grep -qF THAT {} \; -print
```

will list only those files that contain *THIS* but don't contain *THAT*.
Anyway, in your case:

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) \
-exec ggrep -qF LARGE_INTEGER {} \; \
-exec gsed -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/' {} \;
```

---

*1*
I assume your `xargs` doesn't support `-0` or `--null` option. If it does, use the following construct:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lFZ SOME_STRING {} + | xargs -0 gsed -s -i 'COMMAND'
```

i.e. in your case:

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) \
-exec ggrep -lFZ LARGE_INTEGER {} + | \
xargs -0 gsed -s -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/'
```

It should be more efficient than the first one.
Also, both will work with all kind of file names. Note that I'm using `grep` with `-F` (fixed string) as it is faster so remove it if you're planning to use a regex instead.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Your codes 4-5 are great! This flag `-size -5k` is time-saver because I have had files which size is >200 Mb as binary data. Why do you use `-print` in codes 2-3? I do not find it intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output of `gfind` to `xargs`:

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec ggrep -l "LARGE_INTEGER" {} + | xargs sed -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/'
```

Notice that I've removed the `-P` option from `ggrep`, since you're matching a fixed string.

However this solution doesn't deal well with filenames containing newlines; a safer way to do this would be to force `gfind` to output NULL terminated filenames and to loop over the output in a `while` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

gfind /tmp/ -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -print0 | while read -d '' -r filepath; do
    [ "$(ggrep -l "LARGE_INTEGER" "$filepath")" ] && sed -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/' "$filepath"
done
```

If you like one-liners:

```
gfind /tmp/ -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -print0 | while read -d '' -r filepath; do [ "$(ggrep -l "LARGE_INTEGER" "$filepath")" ] && sed -i '1s/^/#include <stdint.h>\n/' "$filepath"; done
```

Comment: I like the while loop approach a lot since easy to read and edit afterwards. Any idea about efficiency in comparison to Don?

Comment: @Masi I think don_crissti's first showcased method is more efficient than my second showcased method, however as you said using a `bash` script might fit better if you're in sight of do further processing of the input. If that's it, just use don_crissti's first or second showcased method (or my first showcased method, which matches don_crissti's second showcased method), otherwise use my second showcased method, which will probably fit further expansions a little better.