# grep and sed in specific

Tags: sed, grep, find

I am struggling to find a way to replace all the lines with the following information in *.tex files for example:

```
text{fig/titel/Logo}text
```

to

```
text{fig/titel/Logo.png}text
```

I have tried:

```
egrep --include=*.tex -r ".*{fig/.*" *
```

and it gives me the lines where I want to make the changes. But how do I proceed further with the sed command for example?

I have used find and sed, but never used grep and sed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are the words you want to change always `titel/Logo` or could they be different?

Comment: could be different.. Finally a .png should be added. the problem is that pdflatex takes png as default, but latexmk needs an extension.

Comment: could be different.. A .png should be added in the end. The problem is that pdflatex takes png as default and hence the code works fine, but  latexmk throws an error, as it needs a specific extension for the image file.

Comment: Same as [find: multiple `-exec`s with conditions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212957)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `GNU` tools (which you seem to be using):

```
grep -r --include='*.tex' -lZ '{fig/.*}' . |
  xargs -r0 sed -i.back 's:\({fig/[^}]*\)}:\1.png}:g'
```

`grep` to find the list of files to update, `sed` to do the update only for those files.

Or if you only want to add the `.png` if it's not there already, GNU `grep` has a `-P` option for PCRE regexp with its `(?<!...)` negative look-behind operator, but not GNU `sed` yet (though `ssed` in the same family does), so switching to `perl` here:

```
grep -Pr --include='*.tex' -lZ '\{fig/[^}]*(?<!\.png)\}' . |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi.back -e 's:(\{fig/[^}]*(?<!\.png))\}:$1.png}:g'
```

With `-i.back`, the original file is saved with the `.back` extension.

Comment: I actually tried this before. The error is sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'. I have to say, that the grep results are strange, because all the files where the expression is found are one after another in one row without any space between the two found files.

Comment: You probably tried with `s/.../.../` instead of `s:...:...:` and so had an issue with the embedded `/` in `{fig/`. With `-lZ`, the file names are NUL delimited so it can be safely handled by `xargs` (with `-0`). The `NUL` character is invisible when sent to a terminal.

Comment: Oops, I have a new problem. Some of the lines are already with extensions png. Ofoucrse, now all of them have been appended with an added .png :D. Is there a way to just do the substitution only if there isnt a png in the end.. I know basics of regex, but these are quite complicated expressions.

Answer (score 1):

When using `sed` you don't need `grep`, because `sed` can do pattern searches at the same time.

In this case it's a pretty simple expression; look for the string `{fig/` and then append a `png`

Now the search expression needs to be a little more clever, since we want to stop at the closing `}` character, but that's pretty normal.  We should also take into account that there may be more than one per line.

So we end up with

```
sed 's!{\(fig/[^}]*\)}!{\1.png}!g'
```

For example:

```
$ cat x
untouched lines
text{fig/titel/Logo}text
more lines
text{fig/somethingelse/image}text
text{fig/stuff}text and {fig/morestuff}text

$ sed 's!{\(fig/[^}]*\)}!{\1.png}!g' x
untouched lines
text{fig/titel/Logo.png}text
more lines
text{fig/somethingelse/image.png}text
text{fig/stuff.png}text and {fig/morestuff.png}text
```

We can see that the `{fig/...}` entries now have `png` appended and other stuff is untouched.

Comment: But when using GNU `sed -i`, you may want to actually only modify the files that need to be modified, so using `grep` and `sed` may actually make sense.

Comment: Thanks, is there something called a dry-run or interactive mode while running the above?

Comment: Should the x replaced by *.tex, since I only want to modify the tex files?

Comment: When using `sed` in this way it doesn't change the file, so it is effectively dry-run mode.    You would add the `-i` flag to do an "in-place" change and update the file.  eg `sed -i 's!......!g` mytext.tex`

Comment: Looks like it is working. But, can you please tell me if I can do it recursively in all files and directories?

Comment: The `sed` command is designed to work on a single file at a time.  You would need to wrap it (eg in a loop, or via `xargs`) to make it work on multiple files.  How you do the loop does the recursion;  eg something like `find . -name '*.tex' -exec sed -i.bak 's!....!g' {} \; `